# Create Fixed Navigation menu in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, nav

How can I fix (fixed at top while scrolling ) my WordPress powered website's navigation menu like TechCrunch.com?

Answer (score 3):

To keep your navigation on top of the site at all times use the following css for your menu container:

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
position: fixed;
padding: 5px 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

Then you may use some JavaScript to change the logo size if user scrolls down.
I would reccomend to use jQuery library to check the navigation bar position, change it's position in case user scrolled more than the height of the navigation top keep it on top of the window and of course repeat the whole process when user scrolls.

You can find good and simple tutorial in [here](http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/6-navigation-menu-that-stays-on-top-with-jquery)

The jQuery code needs to be placed in your header.php file, first by attaching jquery library `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquerylibrary.js"></script>` and then by placing your code within the `<script>` tags also in the header php

Comment: This code fixes Nav Menu at top of the page i.e. above header. 
This is my site: [link](http://www.windowsphonestore.com/)
I want to fix category nav menu (the one with green background) when page scrolls after the header. Like http://hellboundbloggers.com/

Comment: This is my site: [Windows Phone Store](http://wwww.windowsphonestore.com/) .. I want to fix category nav menu (the one with green background) when page scrolls after the header. Like hellboundbloggers.com

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. One more thing, I am new to jQuery. I don't know where to place that jQuery code in my WordPress theme. Please help